# MySQL - If an insertion fails during a transaction, will an exception or warning ALWAYS be raised?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

I'm using MySQL Connector/Python to call the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddDishReview
(
    id INT,
    OUT retVal TINYINT(1)
)
this_proc:BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (id);

    IF ROW_COUNT() < 1 THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        LEAVE this_proc;
    END IF;

    SET @table1RefID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (@table1RefID);

    IF ROW_COUNT() < 1 THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        LEAVE this_proc;
    END IF;

    SET retVal = 1;
    COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

My question is, if an insertion fails, will there *always* be an exception or warning raised (which would in turn trigger the exit handler)? I just can't help but feel like all of the `IF ROW_COUNT < 1` checks are unnecessary. But I put them in there because I wasn't sure if it was possible for an insertion to fail without raising an exception/warning (which would result in execution continuing and a `ROW_COUNT` of 0).

tl;dr: Is it safe to assume that if no exception or warning is raised, the insertion succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will get either an error or a warning if an insert statement fails. Mysql documentation on [sql mode setting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#ignore-strict-comparison) has a nice summary table that describes when you get an error and when you get a warning for various sql mode / ignore scenarios. As you can see from the linked table, no warning is ever ignored, but errors may be reduced to warnings.